# Passing string (or httprequest) from one class to another

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a string in a class that I would like to access from another class.

I would like the strings `responseString` or `result` (from the `onPostExecute()`) to be accessible in my `Registration.java` class.

Here is the `RequestTask.java` with the string that I need:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
      //needed string
      String responseString = null;


  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpResponse response;

      try {
          response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
          StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
          if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
              ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
              out.close();
              String responseString = null;
              responseString = out.toString();
              Log.d("check response", responseString);



          } else{
              //Closes the connection.
              response.getEntity().getContent().close();
              throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
          }
      } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
          //TODO Handle problems..
      } catch (IOException e) {
          //TODO Handle problems..
      }
      return responseString;
  }





  public void onPostExecute(String result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);



}



}
```

Here is the `Registration.java`, I would like the string to show up in the `else` statement at the very bottom:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Registration extends Activity {

    String result2 = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);
          TextView detail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resulttext);
            detail.setText(result2);
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void SubmitRegistration(View view) {




           // assign text in fields to string values
           EditText first = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.first);
           String first2 = first.getText().toString();

           EditText last = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.last);
           String last2 = last.getText().toString();

           EditText display = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.display);
           String display2 = display.getText().toString();
           //calculates the number of characters in the display field
           int length2 = display2.length();


           EditText email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
           String email2 = email.getText().toString();


           EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
           String password2 = password.getText().toString();


           EditText vpassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.vpassword);
           String vpassword2 = vpassword.getText().toString();
           //calculates the number of characters in the password field
           int length = vpassword2.length();






    // verifying the following in order:  Passwords match? A Password field is empty?  
                                        //Password and Display Name less than 6 characters long? Email contains an @ sign and a period?   
           if(!vpassword2.equals(password2))
           {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Passwords do not match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 


           }
           else if (password2.isEmpty() || vpassword2.isEmpty()){

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password field is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
           }
           else if (length < 6 || length2 < 6 ) {

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password and Display Name must be at least 6 characters long", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

           }

           else if (!email2.contains("@") || !email2.contains(".")){

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Must enter valid email address.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

           }

           else {

               String asd = "http://www.alkouri.com/android/registercheck.php?first=" + first2 + "&last=" + last2 + "&dispname=" + display2 + "&email=" + email2 + "&password=" + password2;
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), froyo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
               //send php with all the data to server for validation and insertion into table
               new RequestTask().execute("http://www.alkouri.com/android/registercheck.php?first=" + first2 + "&last=" + last2 + "&display=" + display2 + "&email=" + email2 + "&password=" + password2 );                       



           }
   }





}
```

I have tried making it `public void` but I still can't access it in `Registration.java`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding your onPostExecute(String result) method from the Reqeust task:

sample:

```
String asd = "http://www.alkouri.com/android/registercheck.php?first=" + first2 + "&last=" + last2 + "&dispname=" + display2 + "&email=" + email2 + "&password=" + password2;
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), froyo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
//send php with all the data to server for validation and insertion into table

RequestTast task = new RequestTask()
{
     @override
     public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ... do something with the resut.. 
     }
}

task.execute("http://www.alkouri.com/android/registercheck.php?first=" + first2 + "&last=" + last2 + "&display=" + display2 + "&email=" + email2 + "&password=" + password2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

In `onPostExecute(String arg)` you can start your Activity

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
      //needed string
      String responseString = null;
     private Context mContext;

  //This is where you pass the context
  public RequestTask(Context context) {
       mContext = context;
  }


  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpResponse response;

      try {
          response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
          StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
          if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
              ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
              out.close();
              String responseString = null;
              responseString = out.toString();
              Log.d("check response", responseString);



          } else{
              //Closes the connection.
              response.getEntity().getContent().close();
              throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
          }
      } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
          //TODO Handle problems..
      } catch (IOException e) {
          //TODO Handle problems..
      }
      return responseString;
  }





public void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Intent i = new Intent(mContext Registration.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("REGISTRATION", result);
    i.putExtras(i);
    mContext.startActivity(i);
 }



}
```

Then, in your Registration Class you do this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String myResult = (String) b.getString("REGISTRATION");

    setContentView(R.layout.register);
    TextView detail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resulttext);
    detail.setText(result2);
}
```

And Finally, when you call your RequestTaskt class, you pass the Context through parameter, like this `RequestTask mTask = new RequestTask(getActivity());`

Comment: I tried using intents but every time I use context, I get this:

`The method getContext() is undefined for the type RequestTask`

Comment: So I am assuming by `mContext` you meant `Context` in the onpost.

This is still not working though :(  The same problem that has plagued be for the past 48 hours and I don't know how to get past it.  I get the following error:

`The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type RequestTask` and `The constructor Intent(Class<Context>) is undefined`



even though I have the following imports at the very top:

`import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;`

Comment: No, I meant the context of the Activity where you create your `RequestTask` object. But, to solve your problem, change `startActivity(i)` for `mContext.startActivity(i)`